# Angular http post error: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, dependency-injection

I am trying to make my first http POST request. I have the GET request working fine (in the same service), but when I try and make a POST request I am getting the error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
>           at 
>       ApiService.push../src/app/services/api.service.ts.ApiService.getTracsStartEvents
>   (api.service.ts:57)

I'm using it in the same way I'm using the GET request, in the same file. I don't understand why the POST request isn't working. I must have something wrong syntactically. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
import { Device } from '../shared/device';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ApiService {
  TRACS_URL = '<REMOVED>';
  DELORME_LOCATE_URL = '<REMOVED>';

  apiKey = '<REMOVED>';
  getAllDeviceAPI = 'PApps_AircraftInfo';
  getDeviceByIMEIAPI = 'PApps_AircraftInfo/FindByIMEI/';
  getDeviceByTailNumberAPI = 'PApps_AircraftInfo/FindByTailNumber/';
  getDeviceByCallsignAPI = 'PApps_AircraftInfo/FindByCallsign/';
  getTracsStartEventsAPI = 'GetStartTrackEvents';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  public createDevice( device: Device ){}

  public updateDevice( device: Device ) {
    console.log('going to call API to update device: ', device)
  }

  public deleteDevice( device: Device ) {
    console.log('going to call API to delete device: ', device);
  }

  public getDeviceByIMEI( imei: string ) {
    return this.httpClient.get<Device[]>(`${this.TRACS_URL}/${this.getDeviceByIMEIAPI}/${imei}?apikey=${this.apiKey}`);
  }

  public getDeviceByTailNumber( tailNumber: string ) {
    return this.httpClient.get<Device[]>(`${this.TRACS_URL}/${this.getDeviceByTailNumberAPI}/${tailNumber}?apikey=${this.apiKey}`);
  }
  public getDeviceByCallsign( callsign: string ) {
    return this.httpClient.get<Device[]>(`${this.TRACS_URL}/${this.getDeviceByCallsignAPI}/${callsign}?    apikey=${this.apiKey}`);
  }
  public getAllDevices( url?: string ) {
    return this.httpClient.get<Device[]>(`${this.TRACS_URL}/${this.getAllDeviceAPI}?apikey=${this.apiKey}`);
  }

  public getTracsStartEvents( imeiList: string[] ) {
    console.log('imeiList: ', imeiList );
    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
        'x-api-key': 'Ra4GyPWuzU1PKDKdmHyyK4WlMKV7v3j4JQhaU7i8',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    });
    let options = {
      headers: httpHeaders
    };
    return this.httpClient.post<any[]>    (`${this.DELORME_LOCATE_URL}/${this.getTracsStartEvents}`,
      {
        data: { arr_imei: imeiList,
                searchType: 'REALTIME',
              }
      }, options ).subscribe( res => {
        console.log('query result:', res );
      });
    }
}
```

Here is where I call the post function (this is from another service that is to get location updates):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

import { GeoJson } from '../shared/geo-json';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class PositionUpdateService {
  positionUpdate: GeoJson;

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService,
              ) {
    this.positionUpdate = new GeoJson( 'Feature',
    {type: 'Point', coordinates: [-121.0, 37.5, 1000]} );
    //console.log('posUpdate: this.positionUpdate: ', this.positionUpdate );
 }

  getMissionStartEvents( devices ) {
    console.log('posUpdate svc, getMissionStartevents, imeis: ', devices);
    const events =  this.apiService.getTracsStartEvents( devices );
    console.log(events);
  }
}
```

and where it all starts in my `HomeComponent`:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
   constructor(public appSettingsService: AppSettingsService,
               public layerControlDialogComponent: MatDialog,
               private devicesToTrackService: DevicesToTrackService,
               private positionUpdateService: PositionUpdateService,
               private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  startTracking(devices) {
     console.log('going to start tracking ', devices);
     this.positionUpdateService.getMissionStartEvents(devices)
  }
```

Comment: How are you calling `getTracsStartEvents`?

Comment: The only line with `post`  I can see is `return this.httpClient.post` so the logic tells me that `this.httpClient` is undefined. Check your code or try to reproduce it on stackblitz.com so we can examine the problem.

Comment: But I use httpClient in the function above. That is what makes no sense to me why it would undefined two lines later

Comment: Because the `this` reference depends on the way the function is called. You have to use an arrow function instead of an anonymous function (at least thats my assumption). Please add the code snippet where you call `getTracsStartEvents`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to annotate your `ApiService` as `Injectable()`:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ApiService {
```

Then, don't create the `ApiService` yourself, that's what dependency injection is for. It will automatically create an instance of `ApiService` with its dependencies (`HttpClient` in this case):

```
export class PositionUpdateService {
  // The dependency injection will automatically instantiate ApiService
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
   }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: It is injectable. But now when I get rid of creation of the object, I get a different undefined error- now it returns ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTracsStartEvents' of undefined

Comment: Injectable with `provideIn: 'root'`?

Comment: How do you instantiate the `PositionUpdateService`? It also has to be created by the dependency injection.

Comment: That was the magic button! I was manually instantiating the UpdateService in the home component and that was to theroot cause of the issue! Thank You!

Comment: Glad it's working for you now. :-) I recommend reading https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Answer (score 0):

First of all, http.get and http.post return observables, wish would not execute unless you subscribe to it, like this:

```
this.apiService.getTracsStartEvents(devices).subscribe()
```

Second, dependency injection in Angular doesn’t work like this.

1. Don’t use new keyword to instantiate apiService, use it directly like you would use httpClient by simply using this.apiService.
2. Lastly be sure you have provided apiService, if not, put this:

   ```
   @Injectable({providedIn: ‘root’})
   export class ApiService { ...
   ```

And the get method shouldn’t be working, either. If you try to subscribe to it, you will have the same error, probably because of the apiService instantiation in the constructor.